# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying upload image to database using Java.
I've used following code to do that work.

```
File file= new File("image.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("image.jpg");

String query = "insert into mytable(id,image) values(?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = dbConn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setInt(1, sid);
stmt.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int) file.length());

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

But it throws me this error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: are you sure the exception is at image part? or id?

Comment: I can't find where the error is. As I understood, it says there aren't any parameters. But as I saw in Java help, this is the way to do it.

Comment: Can you show full stacktrace?

Comment: @mgamulin This is a problem which one of my friend asked me. This is only information I have now. Will try to get that info from him. Thanks for concern.. :) What I can't understand is, examples which I found in web and according to Java help, this is the correct way to do it. Why doesn't identify parameters?

Comment: Can you set breakpoint on line after File file = new File("image.jpg"), and see what is file.length. Are you sure that your image path is valid, I'm not to sure that it is.

Comment: @mgamulin Thanx.. Problem was in file. :) Thanx for help..

Answer (score 1):

Feels like you have an error at "FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);" may be i,m wrong, but what is 'fin'?. you should give that argument to be 'file'.
Try doing

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

This might work.

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake. File name is variable in my code. I removed it for here. But I forgot to remove all. I edited question. Thanks for mention it.